# HTML: what are the percentages of the heading tags?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have just normalized the font size with this:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
}
```

Now I would like to resize the heading tags giving percentages to the `<h1>, <h2>`. Something like this:

```
h1 {font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0;}
h2 {font-size: 180%; margin: .83em 0;}  
h3 {font-size: 1.17em; margin: 1em 0;}
h4 {font-size: 1em; margin: 1.33em 0;}
h5 {font-size: .83em; line-height: 1.17em; margin: 1.67em 0;}
h6 {font-size: .67em; margin: 2.33em 0;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-weight: bolder;}
```

As you can see, I gave a percentage to the h2, but what are the percentages for the rest of them?

Comment: You only need to set font styles in body, div, input and the rest will inherit from those elements. Seems like you're applying a lot of styles where they don't even need to be applied. Also, the center element is deprecated, you shouldn't be using it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link with a conversion [table](http://www.metahead.com/converting-font-sizes-from-pixel-point-em-percent).

Answer (score 1):

View the falowing link, it might help you solve that:

[CSS FONT SIZE em vs px vs pt vs %](http://www.kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Answer (score 0):

The percentages can be whatever you want them to be. There's nothing saying that an H1 has to be bigger than an H2, that's just the default.

Comment: True on that, but it seems that user248959 wants to follow some kind of rule, and for that, a conversion table is good ;)